# What decimal is between 0.5 and 0.625

Tags: rational-numbers

I would really appreciate some help with this. I have been literally stumped with it for an hour. So if you know the answer please comment below! Thank you for your time:)

Comment: It's completely unclear _what_ issues you are having with this.

Comment: There are infinitely many. Do you mean which one is exactly halfway between? That would be the average of the two.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 5):

There are many decimals between 0.5 and 0.625 - in fact, there are more than you could ever count! So it's a little hard to know exactly what you're asking for.

Possibly, you're looking for the number *exactly* between 0.5 and 0.625, which you find by adding them together and dividing by two to get $(0.5 + 0.625) \div 2 = 1.125 \div 2 = 0.5625$.

On the other hand, maybe you're looking for *any* number that lies between the two, in which case you have many lovely options, including 0.57, 0.624999 and 0.555666777888999.

Or maybe you're looking for another particular number between them, maybe one that has a particularly simple form? You might be looking for 0.6, since it has the shortest (so to speak) decimal representation.

Is it any of those? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean mean or average.

In that case,

$$\frac{0.5+0.625}{2}=\frac{9}{16}=0.5625$$

If you mean what fraction is between those two numbers, there are infinitely many rational numbers bounded between those two.

Comment: I think you mean $\frac9{16}$, not $\frac58=0.625$; also, I think the OP wanted the answer in decimal form.

Comment: Yes they want it in decimal form

Answer (score 0):

There are an infinite number of rational numbers between 0.5 and 0.625 .

A method for picking some of them. Take the difference 
$$ 0.625 -0.5 = 0.125 $$
Then pick any (rational) number between 0 and 0.125 and add it to 0.5 . The result will be another rational number between 0.5 and 0.625.

E.G.  0.1 is between 0 and 0.125. Therefore 0.5 +0.1 =0.6 is a rational number between 0.5 and 0.625.